# how to serach by all ids in parent and children in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a C# POCO with this structure:

```
public class Subject{
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public Guid Id{get; set;}
   public List<Subject> Subsubject{get; set;}
}
```

And store this data in elasticsearch. how can retrieve data using a GUID value which I do not know is the Id of which level of my structure?

I need to search on all Id fields of my structure. is it possible? and if the answer is **YES**, How?
It is preferred to retrieve the owner of id and not whole the object.

```
{
  "Subject" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "subSubject" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "subSubjects" : {
              "properties" : {
                "id" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "title" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "title" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how does your mapping look like?

Comment: I Update my questions with mapping

Comment: So, if I understood your question correctly, you are trying to query all those documents whose outer Id or the inner Id match the Guid you are searching with?

Comment: Yes that's right ... you got the point